# Using Multiple Timers in the .NET Framework

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've got an MDI Form with a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) that slowly ticks to log out employees after a certain amount of time.

Also, there are other forms that may or may not be in use that also use timers. Some timers are for reading from the [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx), others are for processing text as it is either typed in or as records for it change in the SQL 2000 database.

Now, I am about to add another timer to a new form that also will be using the Serial Port.

There is only one (1) Serial Port that will be used on the PC, so I have already redesigned the application so that the MDI Parent contains the Serial Port object and just passes references to the forms that need them.

Now, I am starting to think more about these Timers.

I started thinking about redesigning my MDI Parent to have a universal Tick Event that everything could listen in on using a delegate.

But then I got to thinking: I wonder if Visual Studio does this already?

So, if I add multiple Timer controls to a Windows Form project, does Visual Studio (or the .NET Framework) simply plug in a listener or something to a much larger timer that is always running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timers don't "run", really. A timer sets an operating system trigger to fire at a particular time.

No, it's not better to create a universal Tick event. If you did that, then things that are scheduled to happen once per minute are going to get once-per-second ticks that they'll have to ignore. You'll end up writing a bunch of complicated and fragile code.

Happily, Windows does all that for you. The underlying timer code does essentially what you're talking about doing. It has a universal tick that it listens to, and dispatches events to your timers as required. If you implemented this yourself, you'd end up duplicating what Windows already does much more effectively.

Comment: Sweet! The more I thought about implementing my idea, the more I thought, "This has got to be done already in the framework!" That's why I wanted to ask.